# Problem with Tomcat: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Sorry if repost

I’m new to JSP. I’m following a tutorial from a book, but I’m facing  a problem in  one of the first steps of the example web app.

I’ve installed the Tomcat 6.0, and this is it’s full path: 
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0

The book says that to start Tomcat, I must cd into the Tomcat home directory and run bin/startup.sh, but since there is not any startup.sh file into bin folder, I do bin/tomcat6.exe.
I don’t know If that is right, but Tomcat seems to start correctly that way.

But here is the problem : I created a folder (named Beer-v1) with an HTML form inside (form.html), and I placed everything into the already existing folder webapps. 
This is the full path of the html file:
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Beer-v1\form.html
So I type in my browser: http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/form.html , but the page “503 Service Temporarily Unavailable” is displayed, and not the form.html.
What am I doing wrong?. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BalusC, your answer was correct, why did you remove it?

Comment: @The: You was right in your comment (and answer), OP was using Windows-specific installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The book says that to start Tomcat, I
>   must cd into the Tomcat home directory
>   and run bin/startup.sh, but since
>   there is not any startup.sh file into
>   bin folder, I do bin/tomcat6.exe.

If you don't have `TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.bat` which should be used for Windows instead of `startup.sh` for Unix/Linux, but have `tomcat6.exe` and `tomcat6w.exe`, then you've probably installed Tomcat through an installer.

What you need to do, is on the system tray, find the tomcat logo, right-click on it and start it.
Alternatively, run `Services.msc` (from windows `Run`) and start `Apache Tomcat 6` service.